# Debugging strategy and tools for WebFOCUS

Tags: debugging, bug-tracking, webfocus

My company uses Information Builders WebFOCUS Technology as their Business Intelligence and Reporting tool. That means we have Report data stored in FOC-files and Report query scripts in form of FEX-files to query that data.

However, developing in WebFOCUS is currently done without a proper IDE in Notepad++. This already means that debugging a FEX-script has to be done differently compared to, say, SQL in MSSM. The situation gets even worse as WebFOCUS seems to lack an Output which is showing the developer, what commands are executed at any given moment to better understand what is happening during exeuction of a program.

Are there any best practices to debug WebFOCUS scripts and is there a possibility to track the execution of those?

Answer (score 1):

We use logging almost exclusively to debug with the -TYPE keyword. My advice is to be as detailed as possible because executing WebFocus scripts do not count lines the same as the text editor does so when errors are reported they almost always report a different line than the one which caused the issue in the first place.

There are also a few good tips [here](http://forums.informationbuilders.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/7971057331/m/5507011106) and [here](http://forums.informationbuilders.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/7971057331/m/545102754).